# Why do some websites duplicate their background images, to fill the screen size, rather than upload a larger image in the first place?

Tags: html, css, image

For the past few days, I have been looking at the various ways websites upload background images to their website via CSS.

When it comes to images which can be duplicated endlessly, such as plain stripes, I have noticed that some websites upload a small 'sample' of the image and then duplicate it with a CSS input such as `background-repeat: repeat-x;` rather than uploading a larger version which scales according to screen size.

Is this, primarily, a page load speed optimisation exercise, or is there another reason why somebody may wish to do this other than due to the original image being small in the first place?

Comment: Because they are lazy and don't want to go to the effort of resizing their image. Personally, I think repeated backgrounds look cheap and unprofessional.

Comment: To put it the other way around, if your desired background can be accurately reproduced by tiling a tiny image, with all the convenience speed this gives you, then why _would_ you want to serve a larger image that would likely suffer scaling artefacts?

Comment: @MikeChamberlain Are you saying that from a Page Speed Load perspective, that serving a smaller image and then repeating it via CSS would result in a quicker Page Load Speed, rather than serving the larger image without the need of repetition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this, primarily, a page load speed optimisation exercise,

Yes.

> is there another reason why somebody may wish to do this

A repeating image doesn't have a maximum height or width that using a larger non-repeating image would impose.

Answer (score 1):

This question intrigued me too, I just did a quick Google and from what I found most sites seem to be saying it takes a longer amount of time to download a dimensionally large image than repeat it.

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/making-background-images-load-faster-31826.html

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I have yet to see conclusive proof yet but will post such proof, should I come across it.